# Run time-consuming .exe from Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have an executable that performs long calculations and I want to run those calculations on Azure. What would be the optimal service - batch or VM perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure batch or VM scale sets. Azure Batch is based on top of scale sets and is more specifically designed for task/jobs while VM scalesets help for scaling  generic VMs.

Use cases for Batch:

Batch is a managed Azure service that is used for batch processing or batch computing--running a large volume of similar tasks to get some desired result. Batch computing is most commonly used by organizations that regularly process, transform, and analyze large volumes of data.

Batch works well with intrinsically parallel (also known as "embarrassingly parallel") applications and workloads. Intrinsically parallel workloads are easily split into multiple tasks that perform work simultaneously on many computers.

More info here for batch: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-technical-overview/

Comment: Azure Batch also works with tightly coupled code such as MPI via multi-instance tasks. See [these docs for more info](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/batch-mpi/).

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the doctype to multi-part and you're able to suspend your long job every minute or so and update progress, that will make it more user interactive and stops the http connection timing out. you could also add a cancel job button? or is the question about something else?

Comment: The executable file I have was written in Fortran and automatically reads input files at the beginning then runs for hours. I would like to run more cases of this program and have never been near cloud services before. I am looking for the steps to go from "automated" .exe on my physical computer to what will run off of Azure.